# how to remove other rows with same Word in the SQL table column

Tags: sql, sql-server

how to remove other rows with same Word in the SQL Table column

For example

```
StudentUserID     SessionID 

DSteve             101
DSteve             102   
CJohn              101
```

For Reporting purpose we only need first ever row with StudentUserID

Comment: There is no such thing as a "first" row in a column.  What if there were another row with "Steve John".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the first row that has no overlap with other rows:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where (t2.name like '%' + t.name + '%' or
                         t.name like '%' + t2.name + '%' 
                        ) and
                        t2.SessionID < t.SessionID
                 );
```

This seems to be technically what you are asking for.  It is not clear that this is actually useful.

EDIT:

For your revised question, I'll use a similar query:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.StudentUserId = t2.StudentuserId and
                        t2.SessionID < t.SessionID
                 );
```

Comment: Thank you @Gordon for reply, let me rephrase my question, let say StudentUserID we want to just pick first ever row and ignore others

Answer (score 1):

or make it otherwise

```
 WITH b AS (SELECT t.*,
 row_number() over(partition by student_name order by student_name ) as _rnk 
 from t )
 SELECT * FROM b WHERE _rnk=1
```

although the purpose of that reporting is questionable :)
this will give you a unique student name output others will be dropped
but normally you would want to have a unique id for each student because there can be
multiple John Smiths etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()` :

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, 
             row_number() over (partition by StudentUserID order by SessionID) as seq 
      from table t
     ) t
where seq = 1;
```